# rails paper_trail fail in migration in new server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, paper-trail-gem

I want to deploy a staging server and I use mina to deploy.

I do `mina staging deploy` (work good until the migration)

```
== 20161117192144 CreateHealthCenter: migrating ===============================
   -- add_column(:places, :health_center, :boolean, {:default=>false})
      -> 0.0152s
   rake aborted!
   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "versions" does not exist
   LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"versions"'::regclass
                                             ^
   :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                        pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                   FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                     ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                  WHERE a.attrelid = '"versions"'::regclass
                    AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                  ORDER BY a.attnum
```

The `Place` model have the has_paper_trail (in app/models/place.rb)

The migration of paper_trail is in a migrate of 2017

I have 4 create instances like:

```
Place.create( name: "CESFAM" , address: "Av R 740" , health_center: true )
```

I think this is the problem (now I know I do not have to do data_migration in migration), but I want to know the alternatives solution

I think this solutions

1. Add some config to paper_trail
2. Edit migration removing data-migration
3. other

(sorry my poor english)

EDIT:
    - Rails 4
    - Paper trail 8.1.2

EDIT 2:

Migration 20161117192144

```
class CreateHealthCenter < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        add_column :places, :health_center , :boolean , default: false

        Place.create( name: "CESFAM" , address: "R 740" , health_center: true )
        Place.create( name: "CECOF" , address: "S 185" , health_center: true )
        Place.create( name: "COSAM" , address: "C 1892" , health_center: true )
    end

    def down
        remove_column :places, :health_center
        Place.where("name = 'CESFAM'").delete_all
        Place.where("name = 'CECOF'").delete_all
        Place.where("name = 'COSAM'").delete_all
    end
end
```

Comment: Please add the complete migration file to your question.

Comment: @JaredBeck migration file posted

Comment: It's not a good idea to use models in your migrations. Instead of `Place.create`, use raw SQL `execute('insert into places (name) values ("banana");')`. Models change all the time. That `create` may work one day and not work the next (perhaps you add a new validation). So, never use models in migrations.

Comment: I know this "not a good idea to use models in your migrations" (since 2017) but this project start in 2016 :D

Comment: I found a solution but I do not know the implications in migration flow. The alterative is to change paperclip migration to befor "20161117192144" and then deploy work to deploy in the new server (mina staging deploy).

Answer (score 1):

Paper trail Gem uses versions table, with your code it look like on update it is trying to call paper-trail callback and version table still not migrated must be present in later migration. I hope this have given idea and if possible you can can find and migrate paper-trail migration first.

Answer (score 0):

In `rails` 5 or above you should add the rails version in each migration. So I recommend you to add the version like added below and try running `rails:db:migrate` again.

File : **20180410074207_sample_migration.rb**

```
class SampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    ...
end
```

Comment: sorry is rails v4, and I do not see the relation with paper_trail